# How does the 6502 check the negative flag internally?

Tags: 6502

I am currently developing a subset of the 6502 in LogiSim. One of my main resources is [Hanson's Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FievN.png).

Currently I am developing opcodes for the processor, and my current task is the instruction BPL, where the processor checks the negative flag, and if it is positive goes to a specified address.

My first thought was that the processor puts the status register into the ALU and has the other argument as 10000000, but the ALU compares 8 bit numbers, so I am not sure how it would compare just a single bit of the status register. How does the 6502 check the negative flag internally?

Comment: I don't know specifically for the 6502, but generally speaking the flags in a processor are implemented as a single latch, so to control something based on them you'd just wire the output directly up to whatever needs it.  No ALU usage required.

Comment: @Jules, I imagine you meant each flag is implemented as a single flip-flop, not all the flags in that single flip-flop, as your comment reads :-)

Comment: The flag bit is most likely wired directly to the condition checker.